# Menu positioning with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

At the moment, I am currently working on a web-based game (agar.io spinoff) with the UI based off of Bootstrap 3.3.7. I don't necessarily want to re-code this for Bootstrap 4 to use grids, so how would I do this?
This is what I currently have: (As you can see, i'm running out of room here.)

[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALzpC.png)

[image]
This is what I plan to achieve: (Notice the different sections of the menu side by side and vertically aligned)

[What I plan to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGAVm.png)
[image]
Can someone please figure this out, I've been working at this for hours and i'm stumped. My current css (#helloDialog is the main dialog on the menu):

```
#helloDialog, #scorebox, #news, #about, #myviewskin {
    width: 400px;
    background: #fff repeat scroll left top;
    /* margin: 10px auto; */
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    line-height: 1;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Images showed as links, no clue why...

Comment: bootstrap 3 uses the grid system, take a look at https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/ .  You'll need to declare a container at your page root and then play around with the columns to add your other controls if I understand correctly.  As a bonus you can move your columns around using the linked syntax to make your game responsive to mobile devices.

Answer (score 0):

Don't copy and paste my code but this is how I would do it:

I would create a modal-parent-container that holds a `.row` with three `.col` and within those `.col`, I would include another `.row` that contains `.col` that span the entire width of the `.row`, `col-12`, which then contain the `.panel`s

```
<div class="modal">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="panel">
          </div><!--end panel-->
        </div><!--end col-->
      </div><!--end row-->
    </div><!--end col-->
    <!--include column here with row and column children and panel-->
    <!--include column here with row and column children and panel-->
  </div><!--end row-->
  </div><!--end container-->
</div><!--end modal-->
```

I say not to copy and paste my code because the modal still needs other required markup and you need to include the rest of the markup yourself.

But this will give you the desired look as described in the image you presented.